# Como saber se um NSArray está vazio (ou nulo) usando IF

Tags: array, objective-c, if, sintaxe

Preciso saber se um NSArray está vazio ou nulo usando um if.

Código:

```
NSArray* array;

 if( array == nil)
{ 
   // Fazer algo
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como no objective-c uma mensagem para `nil` retorna `nil`, você pode usar o código abaixo:

```
NSArray *array = [obtem o valor];
if ([array count]) {
    // Nao é vazio nem nulo
}
```

Se o array é `nil`, então o resultado de `[array count]` também será `nil` (o que é considerado "falso" no if). Se não for `nil`, então o método `count` retorna o número de elementos. Se for zero, o if também não vai entrar, já que zero também é considerado falso.

Comment: Encontrei a solução outra solução... usando NULL no lugar de nil!

Comment: Obrigado @carlosfigueira, sua resposta é muito boa!!

Comment: Pra esclarecer melhor o porque usar o `([array count])` no lugar de `NULL` tem um artigo muito legal [nesse link do NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nil/)

Comment: Otimo link!! Obrigado! @iTsangar

Answer (score 1):

Bom, foi mais rápido que pensei.

Usei NULL no lugar do nil, ficando deste modo:

```
NSArray* array;

 if( array == NULL)
{ 
   // Fazer algo
}
```